# Lucene-like searching through JSON objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, lucene, indexing

I have a pretty big array of JSON objects (its a music library with properties like artist, album etc, feeding a jqgrid with loadonce=true) and I want to implement lucene-like (google-like) query through whole set - but locally, i.e. in the browser, without communication with web server. Are there any javascript frameworks that will help me?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "lucene-like" or "google-like"? Lucene does a lot more than just partial-word autocomplete matches; it's an entire framework.

Comment: "Pretty big" isn't exactly much of a quantification. How many records are we talking about? Hundreds? Thousands? Millions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Go through your records, to create a one time index by combining all search
   able fields in a single string field called index.
2. Store these indexed records in an Array.
3. Partition the Array on index .. like all a's in one array and so on.
4. Use the javascript function [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) against the index to match the query entered by the user and find records from the partitioned Array.

That was the easy part but, it will support all simple queries in a very efficient manner because the index does not have to be re-created for every query and indexOf operation is very efficient. I have used it for searching up to 2000 records. I used a pre-sorted Array. Actually, that's how Gmail and yahoo mail work. They store your contacts on browser in a pre-sorted array with an index that allows you to see the contact names as you type.

This also gives you a base to build on. Now you can write an advanced query parsing logic on top of it. For example, to support a few simple conditional keywords like - AND OR NOT, will take about 20-30 lines of custom JavaScript code. Or you can find a JS library that will do the parsing for you the way Lucene does.

For a reference implementation of above logic, take a look at how [ZmContactList.js](http://www.koders.com/javascript/fidE976B364B5DE280840FDCC436BFCC7BB288BF857.aspx?s=search#L36) sorts and searches the contacts for autocomplete.

Comment: You don't happen to be willing to provide me with your current implementation, do you? I'd love to  see it released as a jQuery Plugin (or to turn it into one myself, for that matter) ...

Comment: ZmContactList.js is the implementation and I cannot take credit for it.

Comment: There are many optimizations that could be done but here is a start: http://jsbin.com/osocig/1/edit

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check FullProof, it does exactly that:
https://github.com/reyesr/fullproof

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/)?

Edit:

How about something along these lines (also see http://jsfiddle.net/7tV3A/1/):

```
var filtered_collection = [];
var query = 'foo';

$.each(collection, function(i,e){
    $.each(e, function(ii, el){
        if (el == query) {
            filtered_collection.push(e);
        }
    });
});
```

The (el == query) part of course could/should be modified to allow more flexible search patterns than exact match.

Comment: naaah, I want it to take place in the browser.

Comment: Example in the The fiddle indexes the records every time the query is passed. That's not efficient if you have a large number of records.

Comment: @RHT You're absolutely right. user961474 - how many records are we talking about?