# query lucene index with javascript

Tags: javascript, lucene

I have indexed some data and I now have the resulting index files. Is there any way to query this index from javascript without using anything else than javascript and the lucene index files?

[This project](https://github.com/gsf/node-solr) lets me query an index from javascript but I need solr.

The scenario is that I need to query the index on a client and I only have javascript and the index files available. No internet connection.

Since I do not need advanced search features such as boosting, synonyms etc, I'm thinking of an alternative solution where I create my own inverted index instead of working with a lucene index. Something along [these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531414/lucene-like-searching-through-json-objects-in-javascript).

Does that sound like a better idea?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean as a nodeJs project ?
Its also worth mentioning that Solr works great on localhost.

Comment: And no Java available?

Answer (score 0):

To query the lucene index you required the lucene jar, if you have lucne jar you can write the custom code to query from index. No Internet connection reqired