# how to do a search with an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter

How could I do a search by name and surname with an array javascript?
and every time I search something that begins with je, div=result show me all Name and Surnames with Je in this case Jessica and Jey;
this would be a onkeydown event, right?

```
<input type='text' id='filter' placeholder='search in array'>
```

here I print the result:

```
<div id='result'></div>
```

this is my array :

```
var datos = [ ['Jessica','Lyn',3],
         ['Jhon','Cin',5],
         ['Alison','Peage',1],
         ['Thor','zhov',12],
         ['Jey','hov',32]  
        ];
```

Comment: Could you please show us the search code you have written so far? What's the issue you are having?

Comment: you can use a jqueryui library which is similar to facebook hints while searching friends using @ in comments http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $result = $('#result');

$('#filter').on('keyup', function () {
    var $fragment = $('<div />');
    var val = this.value.toLowerCase();
    $.each(datos, function (i, item) {console.log( item[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(val) );
        if ( item[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(val) == 0 ) {
            $fragment.append('<p>' + item[0] + ' ' + item[1] + '</p>');
        }
    });
    $result.html( $fragment.children() );
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GkWGk/

Comment: @chikatetsu - Just to indicate that it's a jQuery collection.

Comment: @chikatetsu: the `$` in `$result` identifies that `$result` is a variable which is a jQuery wrapper. It is a fast way to differentiate between normal JavaScript variables and variables you can use jQuery methods on without having to wrap again.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#filter").on('keyup', function () {
   var val = $(this).val();
   $("#result").empty();
   $.each(datos, function () {
      if (this[0].indexOf(val) >= 0 || this[1].indexOf(val) >= 0) {
         $("#result").append("<div>" + this[0] + ' ' + this[1] + "</div>");
      }
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MqTBm/

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to run a for loop over the array checking each element. However this is not a good idea if you have a large array. There are many ways to index an array. Thinking off the top of my head I might build a second array that stores the fields joined as one string as the index and then the array reference. So you can for loop through the reference object. Find the entry with string comparisons. Take the index reference to the real array.

Comment: This quasi-related [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531414/lucene-like-searching-through-json-objects-in-javascript) has an answer that better describes what I was talking about.